# Добавить строку только перед первым совпадением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

У меня есть текст:

```
server
abc
location
location
location
something
```

Мне нужно добавить строку ПЕРЕД первым `location`
Используя sed как это сделать?

```
sed -e '/location/\i   то что добавляем' file.conf
```

Добавляет после каждого location, что не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. вам надо задать диапазон строк: `0,/location/` ­— «от самого начала до первой строки, содержащей `location`».
2. и затем использовать команду `s` для замены (я использовал решётку как разделитель аргументов команды `s` для наглядности):

   ```
   0,/location/s#что меняем#на что меняем#
   ```

   подозреваю, что строка, содержащая `location`, содержит ещё какие-то символы в начале (конце), потому вместо `что меняем` надо будет подставить не просто `location`, а `.*location.*`:

   ```
   0,/location/s#.*location.*#на что меняем#
   ```

   а вместо `на что меняем` (т.е., во втором аргументе команды `s`) надо воспользоваться конструкцией, включающей `\n` (символ новой строки), спец-символ `&`, вместо которого будет подставлено всё, что подпало под регулярное выражение в первом аргументе, и вставляемый текст:

   ```
   0,/location/s#.*location.*#вставляемый текст\n&#
   ```

   кстати, чтобы вставить строку **после** найденной, надо всего лишь поменять местами эти три компонента: вместо `вставляемый текст\n&` написать `&\nвставляемый текст`
3. итого (опция `-i` позволяет сразу изменить исходный файл, а не просто вывести результат в *stdout*):

   ```
   $ sed -i '0,/location/s#.*location.*#вставляемый текст\n&#' файл
   ```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Дай Бог вам здоровья!) Помог разобраться, пол дня сегодня не понимал почему в s попадают строки не location, а оказывается 0,/location/ это всего лишь адрес. А в s нужно было писать не s/(.*)/\1/, а s/.*location.*/sdsdsd \n&/

Comment: пожалуйста, конечно. но тут принято [выражать благодарность несколько по-другому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).